# flutter: error during use shared preference

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, dispose

I'm trying to use shared preference to keep user login and I put it in the splash screen and when I run the project this error has appeared:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>
> setState() called after dispose(): _SplashScreenState#aa9c8(lifecycle
>
> state: defunct) This error happens if you call setState() on a State
>
> object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g.,
>
> whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This
>
> error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an
>
> animation callback.  The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or
>
> stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another
>
> solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before
>
> calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.  This
>
> error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called
>
> because another object is retaining a reference to this State object
>
> after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks,
>
> consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().

And the data loop doesn't stop calling itself again and again.

This my method to using shared preference:

```
bool isLoading = true;
init() async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        bool isLog = prefs.getBool("islog");
    
        if (isLog == true) {
          String email = prefs.getString("email");
          String pass = prefs.getString("pass");
          
          setState(() {
            signIn(email, pass);
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        }
      }
    
    signIn(String email, String pass) async {
        var res = await userProvider.login(email, pass);
    
        var user = userProvider.user.tourist;
        if (res is FailedRequest) {
          Dialogs.showErrorDialog(context, message: res.message, code: res.code);
        } else if (user == true) {
          print("Signing in success");
          await appProvider.countryList();
    
          setState(() {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomScreen()));
          });
          
        }
        userProvider.isLoading = false;
    
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
```

this is my splash screen which contain the previous code of shared preference

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
    appProvider = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false);
    init();
    return isLoading == true
        ? Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          )
        : Container(
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    foregroundDecoration: !AppTheme.isLightTheme
                        ? BoxDecoration(
                            color: AppTheme.getTheme()
                                .backgroundColor
                                .withOpacity(0.4))
                        : null,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/introduction.jpg',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: SizedBox(),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 60,
                          height: 60,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(8.0),
                            ),
                            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: AppTheme.getTheme().dividerColor,
                                  offset: Offset(1.1, 1.1),
                                  blurRadius: 10.0),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(8.0),
                            ),
                            child: Image.asset('assets/images/appIcon.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 16,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Voyager",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 24,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 8,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Best Trips deals for your holiday",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 4,
                        child: SizedBox(),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 48, right: 48, bottom: 8, top: 8),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 48,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: AppTheme.getTheme().primaryColor,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: AppTheme.getTheme().dividerColor,
                                blurRadius: 8,
                                offset: Offset(4, 4),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            child: InkWell(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          IntroductionScreen()),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Get started",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom:
                                24.0 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom,
                            top: 16),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            child: InkWell(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.0)),
                              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          LoginScreen(context)),
                                );
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Already have account? LogIn",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
```

So can anyone help me please with my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Pls, call your init function in microtask.

```
Future.microtask(() => {init()});
```

Comment: i got that when i added your line
The class '_SplashScreenState' doesn't have a default constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in '_SplashScreenState'

Comment: You should be using a stateful widget. You can try all the logic here.
 @override
void initState() { 
  super.initState();
  //TODO: Future.microtask(//LOGIC)
}

Answer (score 0):

@Mariam please use mounted,

```
if (this.mounted){
  setState((){
   //Your state change code goes here
  }); 
}
```

Comment: where should i put it please ans how , sorry but i didn't deal with it before

Answer (score 0):

```
use mounted before setState

if (isLog) {
          String email = prefs.getString("email");
          String pass = prefs.getString("pass");

        if(mounted)
          setState(() {
            signIn(email, pass);
          });
        } else {
          if(mounted)
           setState(() {
             isLoading = false;
           });
        }
```

Comment: can you put down your full code? I think it is coming in your splash screen .